# jQuery Navigation Active class reverts on page reload

Tags: jquery

I have the following script that loads on every page in my application:

```
           $(document).ready(function() { 
          $('ul li').click(function(){
            $("li").removeClass("current_page_item");
            $(this).addClass("current_page_item");
          });
        });
```

My navigation html looks like:

```
                <ul id="dropmenu">
                    <li class="active">
                        <%=  link_to 'Home Page',  welcome_index_path %>                    
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <%=  link_to 'Business Owners',  business_owners_path %>

                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Each time I click on the "Business Owners" link, the image to identify the active page first moves from the Home Page link to the Business Owners link and then quickly reverts to the Home Page link again upon page reload. Is there a way in jQuery to persist the state of the "active" link after a page load?

Comment: can you post your html output please?

Comment: I'm guessing you actually have to load the new page, and that return false is'nt an option? If so, changes done with javascript wont work. You either need cookies / local storage, or just harcode it in the HTML or do the logic on the serverside.

Comment: Here is the HTML Output <ul id="dropmenu">
       <li class="current_page_item"><a href="/welcome/index">Home Page</a></li>  <li>
       <a href="/business_owners">Business Owners</a>
       
      </li>
     </ul>

Answer (score 1):

Without having more info, I believe you might be going about this the wrong way. Are you trying to use deeplinking to show/load extra content? If so, your page should not be reloading. You can use jquery address to accomplish this. http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

If your page is actually linking off to a separate page, then this can be accomplished through CSS. One solution is to set a class to the body which styles the active nav correctly.

**HTML**

```
<body class="business">

    <ul id="dropmenu">
        <li class="nav-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-business"><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#dropmenu a {
    display:block;
}
#dropmenu a:hover {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

* active */
.business .nav-business {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tNpVr/